# Python openpyxl: Read only mode returns a different row count

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with an xlsx file using openpyxl, but when I open this xlsx file in read_only mode, I can only seem to access the first 10 rows.  I don't see this with all xlsx files. Is there something about the data in an xlsx file that would trigger the StopIteration early with read_only as True but not when False?  All data in the spreadsheet is (theoretically) uniform and plain text.

This works as expected for book2, but not for book1 as shown below.

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> a = openpyxl.load_workbook("book1.xlsx", read_only=True)
>>> a.active.max_row
10
>>> a = openpyxl.load_workbook("book1.xlsx", read_only=False)
>>> a.active.max_row
20082

>>> a = openpyxl.load_workbook("book2.xlsx", read_only=True)
>>> a.active.max_row
1069
>>> a = openpyxl.load_workbook("book2.xlsx", read_only=False)
>>> a.active.max_row
1069
```

Comment: How did you create the xlsx files? The line count is messed up in VBA when data/rows were deleted, perhaps this is a similar here.

Comment: Thanks for your question.  The xlsx file that doesn't work was generated by a third party program, so I unfortunately don't have control over it. I didn't manipulate it at all, though.

Comment: Looks like the dimensions element in the worksheet has invalid values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `ws.max_row = ws.max_column = None` will fix your problem
quote from docs:

Read-only mode relies on applications and libraries that created the file providing correct information about the worksheets, specifically the used part of it, known as the dimensions.

Some applications set this incorrectly. You can check the apparent dimensions of a worksheet using `ws.calculate_dimension()`.

If this returns a range that you know is incorrect, say `A1:A1` then simply resetting the `max_row` and `max_column` attributes should allow you to work with the file:

```
ws.max_row = ws.max_column = None
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting `AttributeError: can't set attribute` Any idea how to work around that?